# OpenGL texture formats

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

Just to be clear, textures showed perfectly up till now with

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,(GLsizei)img.width(),(GLsizei)img.height(),0,GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,img.bits());
```

Now i want to apply a png image of 9 kb with UV mapping.
This is how my blender file looks (and i export this blender file to .obj for file reading)

[image]

Export Preferences:

[image]

When i execute the above code, i get a segmentation fault (which i never had before)! The file format cannot be the problem because i already tried loading another png texture with succes.
The problem must be the format or internal format of the glTexImage because when i change the internal format to GL_BGRA, it runs but doesn't show textures.

Comment: Did you try `GL_RGBA` instead of `GL_BGRA`?

Comment: "The problem must be the format or internal format of the glTexImage because when i change the internal format to GL_BGRA, it runs but doesn't show textures." That conslusion does not follow, since `GL_BGRA` is not a valid internal format for textures, and the whole command will generate a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error and will have no further effect. To me, this looks like your decoded image data is not in RGBA/BGRA format at all, and you are triggering an out ouf bounds read with that call.

Comment: Ok i solved it. Apparently my png image had an indexed color and i needed to convert it to RBG. But thanks for the responses :)